# jhipster liquibase diff heroku

Tags: heroku, liquibase, jhipster

I have create a very simple Jhipster app and deployed it to Heroku. Everything work fine so I added a new field to my very simple object and redeploy. I got the following error:

```
2016-09-07T12:32:49.375947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/tsts?cacheBuster=1473251569324" host=deplyjhip.herokuapp.com request_id=2b7190f7-0301-456d-87a9-7342640aad9d fwd="5.2.192.47" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=532
2016-09-07T12:32:49.361875+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-09-07 12:32:49.361 ERROR 3 --- [io-40257-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column "amend" of relation "tst" does not exist
2016-09-07T12:32:49.361530+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-09-07 12:32:49.361  WARN 3 --- [io-40257-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
```

I know what happens. When I redeploy using:

```
./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage -x test
heroku deploy:jar --jar build/libs/*war
```

it didn't run `./gradlew liquibaseDiff`

How do I run liquibase diff and apply the changes on the heroku DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems you didn't fully migrated your new field. It looks like you just added the attribute to the Entity class in domain package, but didn't any liquibase migration. You have two option to achieve that:

1. manual migration

just create a "YYYYMMDDHHmmss_add_field_to_my_entity.xml" in src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog directory with a content like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <changeSet id="YYYYMMDDHHmmss" author="you">
        <addColumn tableName="your_table">
            <column name="column_name" type="??" />
        </addColumn>          
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

to make your changes happen. **do not** edit some changelog file, already been migrated in past!

2. adding field to your db, and thenn `liquibase:diff`
   Here you can edit your database using tools you know in order to add that column via. SQL, and then run either `./mvnw liquibase:diff` or `./gradlew liquibaseDiffChangelog` to generate the migration

Comment: I know that this is happening and I now to fix this localy but I don't know how to do this against Heroku database

Comment: if your migration failed only another migration will fix that...in worst case you will have to wipe your database or connect manually to resolve that

Answer (score 0):

In order to run `./gradlew liquibaseDiff` I set the db connection details in gradle/liquibase.gradle as follows:

```
args "--username=USERNAME"
args "--password=PASSSWORD"
args "--url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-BLA.bla.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/DATABASENAME?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"
```

It doesn't work without: `ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`

This generated the changelog so I added it to master.xml and redeploy the app (basically step 2 from the David Steiman's answer)

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly same issue.I used `jhipster entity foo` added a new attribute, and run `./mvnw liquibase:diff`, then I use `heroku deploy:jar target/*.war`, it give me same error.  column "xxx" of relation "xxx" does not exist. I didn't find any solution : ( but remove the database from heroku, then run `jhipter heroku`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not really solve the question asked. The question is why `jhipster heroku` does not run liquidbase migrations scripts even after defining new migrations.

Just add this to the Procfile as a seperate line

```
release: ./mvnw liquibase:update
```

Or you can manually run this commannd, in the run console of your app on heroku

```
./mvnw liquibase:update
```